# reactjs onClick event triggered when the component loads

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I have a component that creates a list with 6 links.

```
//App.js 

{active.map((article, i) => <Article {...article} index={i + 1} key={i}/>)}

//Article.js 

<Reference href={`main/${props.code}`}/>

//Reference.js

<a href={href} className={classes} rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"></a>
```

I need to hang an `onClick` event with the function. I tried all sorts of variations in each of the components, but the function is still called when loading.

Last time i tried this:

```
//Article.js

<Reference href={`main/${props.code}`} onClick={clicked()}/>

//Reference.js

<a href={href} className={classes} rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" onClick={onClick}></a>
```

Tell me, please, how is it possible to do this? Sorry if I wrote the question is not clear, I will be happy to answer any question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use () when setting up an event because it will fire the function immediately. try it like this: `<Reference href={`main/${props.code}`} onClick={clicked}/>`

Comment: funny as I did not notice, thanks for the help! I need to sleep more :D